# What is a type in Pl/Sql

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I was trying to create a procedure which gets a series of input.
At that time I came to know about 'type'. Can you please explain type with an example.

Comment: Did you try to research on your own? Anything specific that you don't understand?

Comment: I saw some example codes in internet. They created a type. I wish to know the use of it.

Comment: @user5505661 "*I saw some example codes in internet. They created a type. I wish to know the use of it.*" Then you should post those examples and narrow down your question. At this stage your question is "too broad".

Comment: @lalith kumar. Thank you for reply. I just want to know abt the use of 'type' in all the sense. I just dont want to know only about its use in that particular code. So only I asked this question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Purpose

Use the CREATE TYPE statement to create the specification of an object type, a SQLJ object type, a named varying array (varray), a nested table type, or an incomplete object type. You create object types with the CREATE TYPE and the CREATE TYPE BODY statements. The CREATE TYPE statement specifies the name of the object type, its attributes, methods, and other properties. The CREATE TYPE BODY statement contains the code for the methods that implement the type.

### Declaring and Initializing Objects in PL/SQL

An object type can represent any real-world entity. For example, an object type can represent a student, bank account, computer screen, rational number, or data structure such as a queue, stack, or list.

Currently, you cannot define object types in a PL/SQL block, subprogram, or package. You can define them interactively in SQL*Plus using the SQL statement CREATE TYPE. See Example below, "Defining an Object Type".

For information on the CREATE TYPE SQL statement, see [Oracle Database SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8001.htm#SQLRF01506). For information on the CREATE TYPE BODY SQL statement, see [Oracle Database SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8002.htm#SQLRF01502).

After an object type is defined and installed in the schema, you can use it to declare objects in any PL/SQL block, subprogram, or package. For example, you can use the object type to specify the datatype of an attribute, column, variable, bind variable, record field, table element, formal parameter, or function result. At run time, instances of the object type are created; that is, objects of that type are instantiated. Each object can hold different values.

Such objects follow the usual scope and instantiation rules. In a block or subprogram, local objects are instantiated when you enter the block or subprogram and cease to exist when you exit. In a package, objects are instantiated when you first reference the package and cease to exist when you end the database session.

````
```
CREATE TYPE address_typ AS OBJECT ( 
   street          VARCHAR2(30),
   city            VARCHAR2(20),
   state           CHAR(2),
   postal_code     VARCHAR2(6) );
/
CREATE TYPE employee_typ AS OBJECT (
  employee_id       NUMBER(6),
  first_name        VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name         VARCHAR2(25),
  email             VARCHAR2(25),
  phone_number      VARCHAR2(20),
  hire_date         DATE,
  job_id            VARCHAR2(10),
  salary            NUMBER(8,2),
  commission_pct    NUMBER(2,2),
  manager_id        NUMBER(6),
  department_id     NUMBER(4),
  address           address_typ,
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER,
  MEMBER PROCEDURE display_address ( SELF IN OUT NOCOPY employee_typ ) );
/
CREATE TYPE BODY employee_typ AS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_idno RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN employee_id;
  END;
  MEMBER PROCEDURE display_address ( SELF IN OUT NOCOPY employee_typ ) IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(first_name || ' '  || last_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(address.street);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(address.city || ', '  || address.state || ' ' ||
                         address.postal_code);   
  END;
END;
/
CREATE TABLE employee_tab OF employee_typ;
```
````

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm)

Comment: thank u . it was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a too broad topic.
Steven feuerstein has explained very well in his book Oracle PL/SQL programming.

Read chapter 11 and 12 which is related to type. You can read this book online [here](http://www.howardsmith.net/manuals/Oracle_PL_SQL_Programming.pdf). Happy learning.

Comment: Thank You for suggesting this book :)